# How to get the web pages from cache and restore data in the forms when i try to reach them from other pages of my site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, caching, breadcrumbs

I have several pages with forms on my website. And I also have breadcrumbs navigation and main navigation. In some sense, the main navigation and breadcrumbs are very similar.

**But what I want is when we click on breadcrumbs links we go to the pages from cache with data that we filled in forms before**.

#### F.e.

I have page1, page2, page3.
I go to page1, put some data in a form. Then go to page2 or page3.
And I want to go back to page1 from my breadcrumbs navigation and see all the data that I've already put in the form.

history.back(); or history.go(); don't work in this case, because for this method we need the strait logic of riching the last page in the hierarchy. But in my case, it doesn't work, because I have both: main navigation and breadcrumbs that duplicating it (pls don't ask why), and the logic of riching the last page in the hierarchy can be chaotic.

I've tried to use windows.location.reload(); because by default, it should reload a page from the cache. But it doesn't work. Maybe I use it in the wrong way. Or there is another way to solve this problem.

html

```
<nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="page1.url">Page One</a></li>
                <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="page2.url">Page Two</a></li>
                <li class="breadcrumb-item active" >Page Thre</li>
                
            </ol>
</nav>
```

js

```
$(window).load(function(){    
        $('.breadcrumb-item a').each(function(index) {
            var link = $(this).prop('href');
            $(this).on("click", function(){
                link = windows.location.reload();
            })            
        });
    });
```

Comment: If you're doing a complete refresh of the page, rather than using the history API, there is no built in mechanism to save the state of the form. You will need to use javascript to either save it to local storage, or somehow send the data to the server to store for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use both https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/ and https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage to save your data as json to the local storage and retrieve them in any page. You have to do this when you change page:

```
jsonData = $("form").serializeArray()
localStorage.setItem('pageOneData', jsonData);
```

Feel free to ask me if it not clear

Comment: thank you very much. I've tried localStorage and combined it with a function that's running every 5 seconds. It works fine in spite of some errors in console :) But I will figure out it.